# Maximize area of a rectangle between parabola and a line

Tags: geometry, derivatives

I was given a task to maximize the area of a rectangle that can be inscribed between parabola $y=1-x^2$ and a line $y=0$ such that one side of the rectangle lies on the $x$ axis. My idea is to somehow parametrize rectangle area and then use derivatives to maximize that area but I am not sure if that's correct nor how to do it..
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\cdot$ You that Area = base $\times$ height = $x \cdot f(x) = x(1-x^2)$. Now you wish to maximize this Area. So find it's critical point.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was searching for. Thanks. My textbook says the solution is $\frac{2 \sqrt{3}}{9}$ but I think they made a mistake.

Comment: Nope, that's right. See it's base times height and $x \cdot y = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$.